# Is it possible to read from 5 Parshiyot on 1 Shabbat?

Tags: calendar, torah-reading

On a regular Shabbat, we read from 2 parshiyot when we have a communal Torah reading -- one parsha in Shacharit and the next at Mincha.

When there is a double parsha at Shacharit (such as Tazria-metzora) or some reason for there to be 2 sifrei Torah taken out in Shacharit, we read from 3 parshiyot.

If a double parsha falls out on a day when there is a separate reading from another sefer, and we take 2 sifrei Torah out, we read from 4 parshiyot, total. The same thing happens when we take 3 sifrei Torah out and read from a single parsha in each in Shacharit and then another in Mincha.

Is it possible in our current calendar to read from 5 Parshiyot? Can a day on which we take out 3 sifrei Torah coincide with a double parsha? Is there another permutation which would have leining from 5?

Comment: Is this a riddle? Why would you need to know this? Consider http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4410/759 ; without a practical application, I think this quesiton should be closed.

Comment: Not a riddle at all. I am wondering about how the calendar falls out and the implications on how many sifrei torah a shul might have.

Comment: If this is about implications for Sifrei Torah than adjacent parshas wouldn't matter, and should count for 1

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/114686/759 if there was a snowstorm on vayeshev 23 kislev...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most Sifrei Torah that can be taken out on 1 Shabbat is 5. And, actually, in many shuls, this will occur tomorrow morning and afternoon, so you may want to be there to witness a somewhat rare event. Here's how:

1. 6 aliyot from parshat Tazri'a
2. the 7th aliyah is from Pinchas for Shabbat Rosh Hodesh
3. Maftir from parshat Bo for parshat Hachodesh
4. A custom to read from parshat Nasso the offerings giving by each tribe for dedication of the Mishkan (Tabernacle). This is read at the end of prayesr each day from beginning of Nissan until Erev Pesach.
5. During Mincha, we read from Metzorah, which may require a 5th Sefer Torah

Note that not every place uses the 4th Torah, but many do.

Comment: @DanF Interesting -- I had only heard of #4 being read from a chumash

Comment: @Danno My shul in Wshington Heights when I grew up used a Torah. It was a bit challenging, as many people were heading out of shul, and the rabbi had to beg for 10 people to hang around a few minutes and guarantee them some kugel and chulent :-)

Comment: @Danno There are all sorts of random Minhagim to read extra things from a Torah (for instance, many congregations read from Chayei Sara if a groom was around). Those aren't Torah reading proper, though.

Comment: "many do" I think you mean "almost none do".

Comment: @DoubleAA is there a list of other minhagim that involve actually reading from a sefer? For the nasi, I hadn't heard of it, nor have I heard of reading for a groom.

Comment: @Danno I don't have one. For every minhag that involves reading there is possibly some community that thinks it's 'better' to read from a real sefer. Again, should these things count towards your question? Who knows because you have given us no reasoning behind your question.

Comment: Frankly, DanF can't there be 6 Torahs if there is a groom there tomorrow? What makes you say 5 is the most?

Comment: @DoubleAA No, I don't think they should (though that is because their reading from a sefer is only a minhag but that explanation might not be persuasive). So I'm comfortable with the answer as received.

Comment: @DoubleAA Within about 30 years, I've been to about 100 shuls. I'd estimate that about half of them read from a Sefer. As I said, it's not the majority of shuls out there. Of approx. 10 shuls in my neighborhood that I frequent, all of them have used a sefer. As I said, that's my definition of "many that I've seen", FWIW. I'm completely unfamiliar with Danno's citing of the chatan minhag. I haven't seen this done anywhere, so I can't comment on this. If it is done as a minhag, then, yes, it could be 6 Sifrei Torah. Otherwise, the one "common" number is as others have stated - would be 4.

Answer (score 1):

The most that can be taken out in one week is 4. Like shabbos rosh chodesh chanuka with mincha a double parsha does not fall out during the 3 torah weeks you also.

Comment: 8th day Chanukah on Shabbat, Simchat Torah on Shabbat, Vayakhel-Pekudei-HaChodesh also all have that feature.