# Torah reading cycle, skipped portions

Tags: haftarah, parsha-torah-portion

If a Parsha is skipped on Shabbos Yom Tov, will it be repeated the following week and if yes, will there be 14 Alyiot and 2 Maftir in total?

Also if a special Haftara is read, what happens to the regular Haftara?

Is there ever a case in the full reading cycle where somebody who attended Synagoge service every week would not have heard every word of the written Torah?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Tom and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Hello, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The basic law (Megillah 31b) is to read the Torah sequentially, but occasionally the sequence is interrupted (such as on Yom Tov) and then resumed. All other breaking points are entirely customary.

Historically some communities read sequentially to finish the Torah every 3 or so years, and others read to finish every year. The latter one is the widespread custom nowadays. To accomplish this, each community combines or splits various customary sections at various times as necessary into a new single reading for that week (with only seven readers and one haftara) to meet that community's goal.

Accordingly, the only way someone who always attends synagogue would miss any verses is according to some minority opinions that prohibit getting through (or what they call "catching up") too many customary sections at once (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/114686/759)) for certain hard to understand reasons. But that is a minority opinion applied to a very rare case.

(Note nowadays, nearly everyone follows one of 2 or 3 common sequences of how to combine and split the sections to accomplish this, and ad hoc rearrangements are incredibly rare.)

Comment: 2 or 3? Eretz Yisroel and Chutz Laaretz (when Yom Tov Shenei is on Shabbos) and what third?

Comment: @Mordechai for instance, this week (what you probably call chukkat) certain Syrian communities will read balak (having read korach-chukkat last week) and others (mostly Baladi Yemenites IINM) read half of chukkat and balak, having read the first half last week with Korach. The custom of splitting mishpatim in two in leap years starting on Thursday existed into the 20th century in French North Africa, I don't know if any Jews still remain there. As is well known Kibbutz Galuyot wasn't great news for minority minhagim.... Of course among the rishonim there were dozens more variations

Answer (score 0):

If a *parsha* is skipped, it will indeed be read the following week. To achieve this, there are some Shabbatot where two Torah portions are being read (it will happen soon with Matot-Massei). This enables every single Torah portion to be read over the course of a year. Depending on how many holidays fall on Shabbat in a particular year, there will be varying numbers of double readings during that year.

The case of the Haftara is different, if a Haftara is skipped it is not pushed to the next week.

See [this article](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3779325/jewish/Why-Do-We-Sometimes-Read-a-Double-Torah-Portion.htm) for more details.

Comment: Maybe worth clarifying that 1. The "double parasha" is not read the shabbat immediately following a "skipped parasha" and 2. Only seven people (+ maftir) read every shabbat, even when there is a "double parasha"